# How do i cancel a purchase in the App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore

I purchase an App (Master Record) it is very low quality (recording always clipped, cannot control input level or find any help)

I would like to cancel my purchase?

Is it possible? how?

NOTE: there is not demo/trial mode for this app

Answer (score 1):

Purchases are considered final.

However, the same has happened to me and I’ve found Apple to be quite forgiving if you explain the situation and ask nicely.

Contact iTunes Support and see if they will refund or credit you. Go to https://reportaproblem.apple.com in your browser, log in, locate the purchase and explain the situation.

Good luck!